# Como puedo hacer un scroll spy sin bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

```
  <html>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div  class="ui secondary inverted pointing top fixed menu">
            <div class="ui container">
                <a id="brand-item" class="item" href="index.html">
                    <img class="ui image" src="assets/img/logo.png">
                </a>
                <div id="right-menu" class="right menu " >
                    <a class="item" href="#about">¿Cómo funciona?</a>
                    <a class="item" href="#register">Registrarme</a>
                    <a class="item" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                    <a class="item" href="timeline.html">Trayectoria</a>
                </div>
                 <div  class="mobile-navbar-toggler ">
                    <i style="color: white; font-size: 25px" class="fa fa bars"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <section id="about"></section>

   <section id="register"></section>

     <section id="blog"></section>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hola Edgar, Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para observar mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla! También te invito a revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que usted quiere hacer se conoce como **scroll spy**.  Tienes dos opciones:

Utilizar alguna librería que haga esto por usted:

https://plugins.jquery.com/scrollSpy/

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

o hacerlo manualmente mediante javascript. En este caso debera usar un evento de la siguiente manera

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   let heightTotal = document.body.scrollHeight;
   if (window.pageYOffset >= heightTotal) {
     let item = document.querySelector('.item1');
     item.classList.contains('someClass');
     item.classList.add('newClass');
     item.classList.remove('otherClass');
   }
 })
```